# Does $\int_{\Gamma}\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\,\Lambda_1(dx)=\int_{\Gamma}\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\,\Lambda_2(dx)$ suffices to prove $\Lambda_1=\Lambda_2$?

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose we have two measure $\Lambda_1$ and $\Lambda_2$ on $\mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$.
They may be infinite measure but for all $\Gamma\in \mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$, and $\Lambda_1\left(\left\{0\right\}\right)=\Lambda_2\left(\left\{0\right\}\right)=0$, we have
$$
\int_{\Gamma}\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\,\Lambda_1(dx)=\int_{\Gamma}\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\,\Lambda_2(dx)<\infty.
$$
Does it follows that $\Lambda_1=\Lambda_2$?

Comment: If the $\Lambda_j$  are $\sigma$--finte then the measures $\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\Lambda_j(dx)$ are the same.

Comment: @SangchulLee Sorry, I forgot to add condition to exclude this case.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Suppose they are $\sigma$-finite. Could you give some comments?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it does.

First note that
$$ \infty>\int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus\left(\frac{-1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right)}\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\Lambda_i(dx)\ge\frac{\Lambda_i\left(\mathbb{R}\setminus\left(\frac{-1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)}{n^2+1}\ ,
$$
so both $\ \Lambda_i\ $ must be $\sigma$-finite.

If $\ \Gamma\ $ is any Borel set with $\ \Lambda_2(\Gamma)=0\ $, then
\begin{align}
0&=\int_\Gamma\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\Lambda_2(dx)\\
&=\int_\Gamma\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\Lambda_1(dx)\\
&\ge\int_{\Gamma\setminus(-a,a)}\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\Lambda_1(dx)\\
&\ge\frac{a^2\Lambda_1\big(\Gamma\setminus(-a,a)\big)}{1+a^2}\ ,
\end{align}
for any $ a>0\ $. Therefore $\ \Lambda_1\big(\Gamma\setminus(-a,a)\big)=0\ $ for any $\ a>0 $, and
\begin{align}
\Lambda_1(\Gamma)&=\Lambda_1\big(\Gamma\cap\{0\}\big)+\Lambda_1\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\Gamma\setminus\left(\frac{-1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\\
&=0
\end{align}
From [Radon-Nikodym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) it follows that $\ \Lambda_1\ $ has a density $\ \varphi\ $ with respect to $\ \Lambda_2\ $:
$$
\Lambda_1(\Gamma)=\int_\Gamma\varphi(x)\Lambda_2(dx)
$$
for any $\ \Gamma\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\ $.  Then
\begin{align}
\int_\Gamma\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\Lambda_1(dx)&=\int_\Gamma\frac{x^2\varphi(x)}{1+x^2}\Lambda_2(dx)\\
&=\int_\Gamma\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\Lambda_2(dx)
\end{align}
for any $\ \Gamma\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\ $, from which it follows that $\ \varphi(x)=1\ $ for $\ \Lambda_2$-a.e. $\ x\ $. Therefore
\begin{align}
\Lambda_1(\Gamma)&=\int_\Gamma\Lambda_2(dx)\\
&=\Lambda_2(\Gamma)
\end{align}
for all $\ \Gamma\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\ $.

Comment: +1 Great answer. One thing, I think you need to assume $\Lambda_1$, $\Lambda_2$ are $\sigma$-finite to use Radon-Nikodym?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the omission.  But $\sigma$-finiteness is guaranteed by the conditions given, so it doesn't need to be assumed.  I've now added a note to that effect.